# Update Magento 2 Search With Images

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

Hoping someone can help, I am guessing I am missing something simple.

When I currently search on the site it shows a dropdown with the product and image beside.

I have recently added new products to the site but they dont show with an image in the search

I have tried a reindex but no joy

Any suggestions?

[image][image]

Comment: check in search functionality are you considering all products which are available in website??or it may be because as it shows it has more count, because it matches many products.

Comment: did you reindex after php bin/magento catalog:images:resize